# running object created by DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_program

Tags: database, oracle

I had an issue with DBMS_SCHEDULER in oracle.I have an external programme(a perl script residing on the server on which oracle is running) which I want to run from my stored  procedure based on certain condition.So for that I learned that an external program can be run by creating DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_program.So I did only that.Now the issue,I have a program object created in oracle and but I am unable to execute this object.I have been trying some thing like this to run this object:

EXECUTE MY_PROGRAM_OBJECT;

But every time I do this it is saying that object MY_PROGRAM_OBJECT is invalid(FYI...I can see this object using select * from ALL_OBJECTS).Now I sincerely think that there must be some other way to run this.unfortunately,I don't seem to find any formal doc. for a running a crated Program object.Now can u plz advice me how it needs to be executed?Is it that for executing I have to create another job and point it from there,for which I dont see any rational.

P.S. I have got execute permission on DBMS_SCHEDULER.
All the help in this regard will be appreciated.

Lots of thanks,for taking out the time!

Comment: Post the additional error detail from *SELECT * FROM dba_scheduler_job_run_details WHERE STATUS <> 'SUCCEEDED' ORDER BY LOG_ID DESC;* and see what that shows

Comment: also, check out this link: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=555102

Comment: Can you post the CREATE_JOB command you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a job that uses the program you created.  Something like:

```
exec dbms_scheduler.create_job(
job_name=>'JOB_RUN_MY_PROGRAM',
program_name=>'PROG_RUN_MY_PROCEDURE',
schedule_name=>'INTERVAL_EVERY_DAY',
enabled=>true,
auto_drop=>false,
comments=>'This will run my scheduler program');
```

Note that the schedule 'INTERVAL_EVERY_DAY' would need to be created via dbms_scheduler.create_schedule.

To run or stop manually, you can use dbms_scheduler.run_job and dbms_scheduler.stop_job.  Use dba_scheduler_jobs to view the status of the job you just created above.

As for the rationale for creating programs, they help you to create more complex situations involving chains of jobs.  You would define your chain steps to point to programs and define rules on how to proceed through the chain (running steps concurrently or sequentially in defined order).

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply.But isn't it bizarre that just to run a programme single time,you have to schedule it.is it necessary to create a scheduler when I just dont require it?I have simple requirement that when ever I get an issue in executing a stored procedure I will call a programme which will will raise an alert.so I doesn't need to be schedule but need to be called on my requirements.Is there some thing I missing?

Comment: you don't need the scheduler unless you want to run something on some schedule.  if you want to run a stored procedure, you just call execute, like: execute my_stored_procedure('Some param');

Comment: I don't need stored procedure.I want to run a shell script from stored procedure.Is there any other way in which I can run shell script from oracle?

Comment: ah, ok.  So call an external executable from Oracle.  You can do this in a few ways, but easiest I think would be a use dbms_scheduler with a job type of 'EXECUTABLE'.  See http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_scheduler.html and http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=555102

Comment: but I will say that it would probably be best long term to put the functionality you need from the external script into Oracle if possible.  If you simply want to send emails or ftp files for example, best to use (or add) the functionality in Oracle so you can reuse in your next project (and avoid the issues going outside Oracle to do fairly straightforward stuff).

Comment: My external script is wirting on a socket.so is it possible to write on a socket from oracle?

Comment: yes, of course.  I do this actually when interfacing with an older tcp server...look into utl_tcp.  And search SO for utl_tcp.

Comment: Lots of Thanks tbone!you have made my months.It was really helpful.Thanks again for your kind reply!